# Is NHibernate still in active development for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I heard somewhere that NHibernate for .NET will stop development because microsoft developed the enity framework. Is this true?

Comment: No, this is not true. In fact, the NHibernate Mafia essentially drafted a petition or vote of "no confidence" in the Entity Framework.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731981/ado-net-entity-framework-and-nhibernate-when-to-use-one-over-the-other for why you'd use one over the other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just about a rumor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that [version 2.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/) was released relatively recently, one would presume that it is still actively being developed

Comment: 2.1.1 was released just on 30th October

Answer (score 4):

Of course NHibernate is in active development. I don't know where you got that from, but speaking of EF... as it currently seems it isn't even close replacing NHibernate.

Look at the [recent commits](http://www.ohloh.net/p/nhibernate/commits) to the NHibernate project to get a feeling of how active it is developed. Also make sure to check out [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info) for anything related to NHibernate development.

Answer (score 0):

i sincerely doubt it. entity framework is an alternative, just like linq2sql was. doesn't mean that it somehow eliminates the need for nhibernate or the functionality it brings.